# Wrong results/pagination when ignoring tags

Tags: bug, tags

**Steps to reproduce:**

- add some `ignore tags` (for me all Magento 2 related)
- go to `unanswered` section
- set X per page

**Expected:**

- show X per page

**Currently:**

- it shows X minus ignored questions (2 instead of 15)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [status by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21093/questions-per-page-not-honored-when-using-ignored-tags) and won't be fixed (see linked Meta.SE question for details)

Comment: Thanks. According to this comment: "Darn, I thought we'd patched that once... will look – Marc Gravell♦ Mar 26 '12 at 6:18" it will be fixed sometime ...